# Problem with Button Sound

Tags: android, eclipse

When I start up my app the main menu comes up and when I click either of the 2 buttons it makes the button sound and then goes to the designated layout. The problem I'm having is that if I go back from the layout to the main screen and try to hit the buttons again it still takes me to the layout but without making the button sound. Any ideas? Thanks for the help.

DragonFruitActivity.java

```
package com.Dragon_Fruit;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class DragonFruitActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // ***BUTTON SOUND***//
        final MediaPlayer buttonSound = MediaPlayer.create(
                DragonFruitActivity.this, R.raw.button_click);

        ImageButton playbutton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.playbutton);
        playbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                arg0.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.playbuttonselected);
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                buttonSound.start();
                startActivity(new Intent(DragonFruitActivity.this,
                        playbutton.class));
            }

        });
        ImageButton settingsbutton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.settingsbutton);
        settingsbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                buttonSound.start();
                startActivity(new Intent(DragonFruitActivity.this,
                        settingsbutton.class));
            }

        });
    }
}
```

Updated DragonFruitActivity.java

```
package com.Dragon_Fruit;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class DragonFruitActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // ***BUTTON SOUND***//
        final MediaPlayer buttonSound = MediaPlayer.create(
                DragonFruitActivity.this, R.raw.button_click);

        ImageButton playbutton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.playbutton);
        playbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                arg0.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.playbuttonselected);
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try {
                    buttonSound.prepare();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                buttonSound.start();
                startActivity(new Intent(DragonFruitActivity.this,
                        playbutton.class));
            }

        });
        ImageButton settingsbutton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.settingsbutton);
        settingsbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try {
                    buttonSound.prepare();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                buttonSound.start();
                startActivity(new Intent(DragonFruitActivity.this,
                        settingsbutton.class));
            }

        });
    }
}
```

LogCat

08-12 21:29:54.379: ERROR/ProfileVideoFrameDrops(5764): PVMediaOutputNodePort :: Early 0 frames :: OnTime 0 frames :: Late 0 frames :: Total 3 frames
08-12 21:29:54.379: ERROR/ProfileVideoFrameDrops(5764): PVMediaOutputNodePort :: Early 0.000000 % :: OnTime 19518016.000000 % :: Late -0.000000 % 
08-12 21:29:58.652: ERROR/ProfileVideoFrameDrops(5764): PVMediaOutputNodePort :: Early 0 frames :: OnTime 0 frames :: Late 0 frames :: Total 3 frames
08-12 21:29:58.652: ERROR/ProfileVideoFrameDrops(5764): PVMediaOutputNodePort :: Early 0.000000 % :: OnTime 19518016.000000 % :: Late -0.000000 % 
08-12 21:30:01.082: ERROR/ProfileVideoFrameDrops(5764): PVMediaOutputNodePort :: Early 0 frames :: OnTime 0 frames :: Late 0 frames :: Total 3 frames
08-12 21:30:01.082: ERROR/ProfileVideoFrameDrops(5764): PVMediaOutputNodePort :: Early 0.000000 % :: OnTime 19518016.000000 % :: Late -0.000000 %

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**: Try this:

```
if(buttonSound.isPlaying()) {
    buttonSound.stop();
}

try {
    buttonSound.prepare();
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

buttonSound.start();
```

([check out Google MediaPlayer state diagram](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html))

Comment: Well that seemed to work for a couple minutes but now its back to where it started. I put my new code up. Does it look right?

Comment: Can you put what you're getting in LogCat when you hit the button? I image there is a stack trace that is occurring whenever the sound doesn't play.

Comment: I've edited my code to deal with sounds that are already playing. Try it again.

Comment: That worked well too but I just figured something out. When I thought that it wasnt playing a sound it actually was. It was just really quiet. I can hear it if I listen clearly. Woould it be a problem with my file its mp3 not ogg

Comment: You can try the [setVolume(float left, float right)](http://bit.ly/r7f5ju) method of the MediaPlayer, but you may want to start a new question as that problem is different enough from the original.